# Cant' get response body from Guzzle EntityBody

Tags: php, guzzle6

I can't figure out how to get the response body from the request.

I've found different answers here, but the problem that I'm facing is that, none of these methods `getBody()` and `getContents()` aren't available on this class, moreover **Guzzle\Http\EntityBody**. So here is the response I want to get the data from:

```
    object(Guzzle\Http\EntityBody)#89 (6) {
  ["contentEncoding":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["rewindFunction":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["stream":protected]=>
  resource(171) of type (stream)
  ["size":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["cache":protected]=>
  array(9) {
    ["wrapper_type"]=>
    string(3) "PHP"
    ["stream_type"]=>
    string(4) "TEMP"
    ["mode"]=>
    string(3) "w+b"
    ["unread_bytes"]=>
    int(0)
    ["seekable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["uri"]=>
    string(10) "php://temp"
    ["is_local"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["is_readable"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["is_writable"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["customData":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["default"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, any idea can be helpful. I appreciate that

Comment: "The entity body object of a response can be retrieved by calling `$response->getBody()`. The response `EntityBody` can be **cast** to a string, or you can **pass true to this method** to retrieve the body as a string." https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/response.html#response-body

Answer (score 1):

You are using Guzzle3 that is outdated and deprecated. Please use [Guzzle6](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) (`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`).

Answering your question directly, just [cast this object to string or pass `true` to your `->getBody()` call](https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/response.html#response-body) (as Yohanes Gultom suggested already).